# Por que meu Client só envia duas solicitações?

Tags: java

Meu HttpClient só tá enviando duas solicitações. O server recebe, retorna os 2 valores mas ele na verdade é um loop que envia um monte de vezes! Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    SendData sender = new SendData();
    String JsonDeDados;
    String infos = "informacoes";

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    CloseableHttpClient clientclose = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:5030/data");

    do {

        JsonDeDados = sender.sendMessageDATA();
        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(infos, JsonDeDados));
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(JsonDeDados);

        post.setEntity(entity);
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        CloseableHttpResponse response = (CloseableHttpResponse) client.execute(post);
        System.out.println("Código da Resposta: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        clientclose.close();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

    }while(true);

}
```

Comment: Como está feita a estrutura do laço? Sem o laço, fica difícil adivinhar o que está acontecendo no controle de fluxo de execução

Comment: é um do while(true) normal, pra ficar enviando eternamente

Comment: Editei o código pra ficar mais completo, mas já me deram downvotes :c

Comment: `clientClose` é instanciados uma única vez e fechado diversas vezes? E não é usado uma vez se quer antes de ser fechado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que pode estar faltando o comando `.releaseConnection();` no seu HttpPost. Possivelmente vai ficar:

```
post.releaseConnection();
```

Tenta isso, se não for, pode ser algo no seu laço de repetição

Comment: Onde eu posso posicionar essa linha? Depois do clientclose.close(); ?

Comment: É, isso mesmo. Tenta e informa se deu certo.

Comment: Funcionou, você poderia dar uma explicação rápida sobre o que esse comando faz?

Comment: Então, como o próprio comando diz, ele "solta" a conexão. Assim você não fica com uma "fila" de requests. Como ele tá dentro do laço, ele abre a conexão, envia, fecha. Abre, envia, fecha. E assim vai. Espero ter ajudado, e recomendo dar uma lida nesse [artigo](https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/)